# Error getting value of input text modified by injected javascript with webkitbrowser

Tags: javascript, python, xpath, webkit, web-scraping

i have an issue getting a value of a input text from a webpage using WebkitBrower in Python 2.7.

Here's the example code:

```
from webscraping import webkit, xpath

url = 'https://duckduckgo.com/?q=webscraping'

user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; TOB 6.11; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; MAAU)'

w = webkit.WebkitBrowser(gui=True,user_agent=user_agent)
w.get(url)

token = xpath.get(w.current_html(), '//input[@id="search_form_input"]/@value')
print token

script = """
$('#search_form_input').val('555555');
"""

w.js(script)
w.wait(2)

token = xpath.get(w.current_html(), '//input[@id="search_form_input"]/@value')
print token
```

The output of the example is:

```
webscraping
webscraping
```

instead of

```
webscraping
555555
```

The xpath works fine (find the control), but doesn't return the modified value by the script injected.

At the displayed webpage the input is modified.

Thanks in advance and happy new year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to make this work.

The problem was in the script... to set the attribute value  must be done using the 'attr' method:

```
script = """
$('#search_form_input').val('555555');
$('#search_form_input').attr('value','555555');
"""
```